# Set a cookie after output has been send to browser

Tags: php, cookies

Is there a way that I can set a cookie after an html output? According to PHP manual setcookie() should be set *before* the output.

I need it for my voting system wherein a cookie will be set after a successful Mysql query. I made it in one file.

Comment: no, its a header, but i don't see why you cant alter your code to accommodate it

Comment: output buffering is not going to benefit you here, if you're doing what I expect (having a form that allows the person to cast a vote, and then wanting to set a cookie reflecting that the person voted.)

Comment: @Dagon,

I'll try to move the php codes above the html output.

Comment: If this is simply a counting script, then there's no problem -- just do whatever you need to with mysql, then setCookie.

Comment: What if with jquery "go" to some php file and set cookie in that file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can set a cookie after an html output?

Technically no. If you would like to set a cookie you need to ensure that no output has been send to the browser so far.

> According to PHP manual `setcookie()` should be set BEFORE the output.

That's correct, otherwise it won't work. So I would even say *must*, not only *should*.

> I need it for my voting system wherein a cookie will be set after a successful mysql query.

A successful mysql query on it's own will not create any output. Only a failed mysql query would if error reporting is enabled. So I wonder if you actually ran into a concrete problem or not.

The mysql query itself should not prevent you from using `setcookie`.

In case you have done already HTML output prior the use of `setcookie` you need to find the place where your HTML output started. Above that line place the [`ob_start`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ob_start) function which will start output buffering.

With output buffering enabled, your program can still "output" HTML but it will not be send immediately. Then you should be able to call `setcookie` with no problems:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html><body>
<?php 
  $result = mysql_run_query($query);
  echo '<h1>Your Voting Results</h1>';
  output_voting_result($result);
  set_cookie('vote', $result['id']);
?>
</body></html>
```

The output buffer will be automatically send to the browser when your script finishes, so there is not much more you need to care about, the rest works automatically.

Comment: My mysql query is inside an html element, <html><body><?php ?></body></html> that is why the setcookies doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the code example in the answer to show how it can work.

Comment: I'll try it out. Btw, I'm using this tutorial http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Creating-a-Voting-Poll-With-PHP-And-MySQL-Part-2/1/...

For some reason, he used setcookies() without ob_start..

Comment: Some servers have output buffering automatically enabled. Then you don't need to call `ob_start();`.

Answer (score 12):

you can use the output buffers so at the top of your script you add ob_start() and this will create a buffer and you can then set the cookie and then end the buffer and flush out to the browser.

```
ob_start();
/* set cookie */
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: There is no need for `ob_end_flush();`, is it?

Comment: @hakre its generally a good coding practise to include both. Clarity is better. Also while using multiple nested ob_start() it will be necessary

Comment: @footy: If nested buffers were used, than `setcookie` would not have given any error. Then an additional `ob_start` would have been redundant. Clarity indeed is better, but throwing statements into code that make no sense is the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Cookies can be set in JavaScript on the client side - see this link for examples: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 3):

No. Cookies are sent in the header so they must be set before the output body begins.

You can, however, use PHPs built-in buffering so it won't actually generate any output until the script has completely finished executing.

`ob_start` is the [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/es/book.outcontrol.php)

```
ob_start();

// send output
// set cookie

ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

The cookie gets set in the http header.  If what you want to do is set the cookie on a vote, then you either need to do a header('Location:...') redirect, or you could have a small iframe where you make an ajax call that does the same thing.

Comment: Why would I need a header location redirect?

Comment: I thought you were trying to use ajax for the vote, and yet wanted to also in the same script set a cookie.  If that's not the case ignore this... all you need do is have your processing occur before you do any output.  Output buffering is not needed -- your output will start once you return html.

Comment: It's not needed so long as you call setCookie before output.  There is no reason to have the setCookie after outputing html is there?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are sent to the browser as part of the response header.  This means that they must be set *before* the server starts writing its response to the request that is being processed (so that the server can specify the correct headers on the response).

I don't know the specifics about how this is handled in PHP, but if I had to guess I would say that the output of a given PHP script is probably buffered by the server (typically Apache) until the script completes, and then the server writes the response after the PHP script has completed execution.  If this is the case, then you should be able to set cookies whenever you want.  If it isn't, then you won't be able to.

I'd suggest simply testing it to see what happens.  Write a PHP script that sets a cookie at the very end of its execution, access it via a browser, and then check to see if the cookie is actually set.

Comment: It won't be, the script will produce a "headers already sent error"

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you can't buffer the output, you can set a cookie after sending output by displaying an image on the current page that accesses a script that sets a cookie.

```
echo ('<img src="http://example.com/mysetcookie.php?uid='.$userId.'">');
```

mysetcookie.php

```
<?php
setcookie('cookie-name',$_REQUEST['uid']);
//output an image - this is a one-pixel clear image
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
echo base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw==');     
exit;
?>
```