# Setting a cookie in an ajax call's echo page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I attempted to set a cookie while in an ajax call page, where you echo the data received by the ajax call and got an error message. I'm not sure what it could mean or how to fix it. Setting cookies works fine when they're not being use in ajax calls page, where you echo the info received.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, 0, '/', ".websiteName.com");
```

Got the following error message. No idea what it could mean.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
```

Comment: Assuming this is happening server-side in your PHP code, it sounds like exactly what the error indicates, you're trying to set a cookie (which modifies headers in the response) too late in the process after the headers have already been sent. If you include the actual PHP code that this call is in, then folks could probably help you more directly.

Comment: When does it send the headers?

Comment: Show the relevant part of your PHP code if you want further help with this so people can see exactly what sequence of events you are doing.  It's much easier for people to help you correct your specific issue than it is to teach generic PHP response handling without any context.

Comment: The part of the code where the ajax calls echo? I have like 50 pages of codes in that section.

Comment: Idk PHP, but probably the headers are probably set somewhere at the beginning... Are you using a web framework?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459974/set-a-cookie-after-output-has-been-send-to-browser and http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php.  My guess is that you have an echo before you call `setcookie()` and you aren't using response buffering. FYI, I've never written a line of PHP in my life and this information was garnered from a Google search.

Comment: @jfriend00 I definitely have an echo before I called setcookie(). In fact I have many echos before I called setcookie(); Does it include all echos even if the if statement if false? Or just the echo statements where the if statements are true?

Comment: Just the ones that actually execute.  Read the two references in my previous comment.  You can either move the `setcookie()` call or enable buffering.

Comment: @jfriend00 Why are you answering php questions if you don't know much about php? o.O

Comment: Because your question has multiple tags I do know something about and I was able to find your problem with a simple Google search.  Don't underestimate some Google searching combined with a good logical mind and knowledge of other frameworks which have similar errors that I have seen.  If you'd prefer I not attempt to help you, I can leave now.

Comment: Also, your question does not actually say it's a PHP question - one has to guess that based on tags and studying the content of the question.  Again, if you just include the relevant portion of the code causing the problem, you will always get faster and better answers.  That's just how StackOverflow works.  People here can answer better when they see your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error, which was not shown implies that the headers have already been set. If you would like to use setcookie() you will need to place the call before any of the HTML has been sent out to the user.

The header information is sent out first and can not be modified post process.

In most cases moving setcookie() to the top after

```
<?php
```

Will solve the error, as long as it placed before any output(html) has been sent out.

Comment: <html> test </html> <?php setcookieHere ?> Something like this?

Comment: What about any echo statements? Does setcookie have to be placed before any echo statements?

Comment: In general you will place setcookie() before the opening <html> tag. In most cases, echoing out content implies that the headers will have already been sent.